# If $f:S^n \rightarrow S^n$ has degree $d$, then the induced map on cohomology $f^* :H^n(S^n;G)\rightarrow H^n(S^n;G)$ is mult. by $d$.

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

Wanting to make sure my proof is correct and no one seems to have asked this question before.

By the Universal Coefficient theorem, $H^n(S^n;G)\xrightarrow{\text{h}} Hom(H_{n}(S^n),G)$ is an isomorphism, where $h$ is the map from the Universal Coefficient Theorem.

We then have a commutative diagram

$$
\newcommand{\ra}[1]{\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\xrightarrow{\quad#1\quad}\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!}
\newcommand{\da}[1]{\left\downarrow{\scriptstyle#1}\vphantom{\displaystyle\int_0^1}\right.}
%
\begin{array}{}
H^n(S^n;G) & \ra{f^*} & H^n(S^n;G) & \\
\da{h} & & \da{h}\\
Hom(H_n(S^n),G) & \ra{F} & Hom(H_n(S^n),G) \\
\end{array}
$$

where $F$ is the map sending $\varphi \in Hom(H_{n}(S^n),G)$ to the composition $H_n(S^n)\xrightarrow{f_*}H_n(S^n)\xrightarrow{\varphi}G$ and $f_* :H_n(S^n)\rightarrow H_n(S^n)$ is the homomorphism induced by $f$ on homology which is, of course, multiplication by $d$.

Since $hf^* = Fh$, for a class $[\varphi] \in H^n(S^n;G)$ represented by a cocycle $\varphi$, and letting $h[\varphi]=\bar{\varphi}_{0}$, we have

$hf^*[\varphi] = F(h[\varphi])=F(\bar{\varphi}_{0})=\bar{\varphi}_{0}f_*=d\bar{\varphi}_{0}=dh[\varphi]=h(d[\varphi])$.

Since $h$ is an isomorphism this implies $f^*[\varphi]=d[\varphi]$.

Comment: This seems standard. Note that you are assuming that you already know that the induced map $f_*:H_*(S^n)\rightarrow H_*(S^n)$ is multiplication by $d$.

Comment: @Tyrone $f:S^n \rightarrow S^n$ having degree $d$ by definitions means the induced map $f_* :H_n(S^n)\rightarrow H_n(S^n)$ is multiplication by $d$.